# Правильно ли? Скрытое меню

Tags: javascript, css, css3

Здравствуйте.

Идея была такой: Нужно было сделать скрытое меню или область с дополнительным контентом. Это обычный блок position:absolute; margin-left:-300px; Чтобы при нажатии на какой-то элемент, эта область становилась видимой (выдвигалось)

Решил дело так

```
$(".h-m-b").click(function(){

 if($(this).hasClass('active')) {

    $(this).removeClass('active');

    $(".hidden-menu").addClass('active');

 } else {

   $(this).addClass('active');

   $(".hidden-menu").removeClass('active'); 

 }
});
```

По сути это добавление класса active у которого свойство margin-left:-18px; к скрытому блоку.

Вопрос: **Правильное ли это решение и будет ли работать в браузерах отличным от Хрома?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Jq кроссбраузерная библиотека, даже IE8 поддерживает (версии 1.х.х). Поэтому проблем не должно быть. Заместо remove/addClass можно использовать toggleClass - делает то же самое, что и ваш код: удаляет класс, если есть/добавляет если нет

```
$(".h-m-b").click(function(){
  $(this).toggleClass('active');
  $(".hidden-menu").toggleClass('active');
}
```

Comment: спасибо. по сути ваш код тоже самое что и мой, только немного короче. У меня правда там еще есть проверка на наличие класса 
  active у самой кнопки, потому-как при повторном клике окошко закрывается.

Comment: @AlexanderSizintsev `$(this).toggleClass('active');` как раз меняет класс  у кнопки, то есть всегда будет чередование, остается расставить изначально в нужном порядке классы у кнопок и блока

Answer (score 1):

В принципе ответ вам уже дали.
Я лишь хочу добавить, что производительней анимировать c помощью трансформаций (если вас не волнует поддержка IE8), а не через top, left. Статья [Пола Айриша](http://www.paulirish.com/2012/why-moving-elements-with-translate-is-better-than-posabs-topleft/)